# LVDS to Singled-Ended - Transmission Line Balun Matching

Tags: impedance-matching, lvds, single-ended, balun

I need to convert a LVDS clock into a single-ended signal. In the past I've used a voltage balun with a center tap on the secondary but I haven't found any good past 1GHz. I need to get to 2GHz in this application and found transmission line baluns good from 4.5-3000 MHz like the [TC-1-13M+](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/TC1-1-13M+.pdf) from Mini-Circuits.

Analog Devices shows an implementation of it on an eval board schematic in their datasheet for the [ADL5391](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADL5391.pdf) (page 13). It looks like R4 is the matching for the output impedance of the IC but what is unclear is why they added R5/R6. Is this to present a 150 ohm differential impedance (R4+R5+R6) to the balun? The balun is 1:1 so doesn't that mean the single-ended output impedance is 150 ohm? The datasheet mentions the balun is 50 ohm. I feel like I'm missing something here.

I'd appreciate any clarification you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice page 3, "Differential Output Impedance", which rises with frequency; and Fig.16.  Most likely they wanted a load resistor to dampen this, and then series resistors to match to 50/100 ohm outputs.  Put another way, it acts as an R-pad or attenuator, which reduces signal level but stabilizes impedance.

Note that many resistors (and capacitors) are provided so the user can add/remove parts and pick whatever balance, impedance, and filtering to a certain extent, they require.

Generally speaking, transformers aren't too picky about the impedances they are used at; you simply get proportionally more loss, less amplitude, or less frequency range.

From such meager data, it's not clear how exactly the TC-1-13M+ would behave at 100 or 150 ohms.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I played around with a attenuator calculator and found this resistor network is an approximation of an H-Pad with 25 ohm input and 50 ohm output impedances with 3dB of attenuation. That makes a lot more sense. Should I do something similar to go from 100 ohm to 50 ohm with minimal attenuation for LVDS to single-ended?

Comment: If you can afford attenuation, that's an option, yes.